# Elasticsearch stops checking must_not when providing two key-value pairs in must_not object

Tags: elasticsearch

This query works fine:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{
                "multi_match":{
                    "query": "ny gammal",
                    "fields": ["title", "description^1.4"],
                    "type": "cross_fields"
                }
            },
            "must_not":{
                "range": {
                    "modelYear":{"gte": 2014}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns all objects with a `modelYear` that's less than 2014. Let's say I want to get all the objects with a `modelYear` between 2010 and 2013. I would do this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{
                "multi_match":{
                    "query": "ny gammal",
                    "fields": ["title", "description^1.4"],
                    "type": "cross_fields"
                }
            },
            "must_not":{
                "range": {
                    "modelYear":{"gte": 2014, "lt":2010}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To my surprise, the query returns the same results as this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{
                "multi_match":{
                    "query": "ny gammal",
                    "fields": ["title", "description^1.4"],
                    "type": "cross_fields"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Meaning the same results as the query without the `must_not` clause.

As far as I can tell, I've done nothing wrong. Is this a bug? How can I make the second query work?

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.

Comment: For the third query, does the results contain only docs which have model year between 2010 and 2013?

Answer (score 0):

A more intuitive (readable) way of doing this would be

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "ny gammal",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "description^1.4"
            ],
            "type": "cross_fields"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "modelYear": {
              "gte": 2010,
              "lte": 2013
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now as far as your solution goes, well it depends on your data.
Provide a minimal test sample showcasing that your query doesn't work.
Provide some sample data and you mapping (omitting the fields that are not relevant).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the original observation. Sample test data is

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/rqs-mustnot/Car/1234 -d '{"modelYear":2002, "title":"ny gammal 1", "description":"ny gammal 2002"}'
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/rqs-mustnot/Car/2345 -d '{"modelYear":2012, "title":"ny gammal 2", "description":"ny gammal 2012"}'
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/rqs-mustnot/Car/3456 -d '{"modelYear":2018, "title":"ny gammal 3", "description":"ny gammal 2018"}'
```

I believe the issue is with the `"modelYear":{"gte": 2014, "lt":2010}` range clause:

This is always false. No date can be larger than 2014 and less than 2010 at the same time.

A `must_not` of such false value is always true. And an always true clause in a `must` array is the same as leaving it away.